# How long does AWS Lambda keep your idle functions around?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, keep-alive

I looked at [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) and also on google and its [result](https://read.acloud.guru/how-long-does-aws-lambda-keep-your-idle-functions-around-before-a-cold-start-bf715d3b810), but could not find the duration before that the AWS Lambda will be cold started.

My aim is to [reuse database connections](https://www.jeremydaly.com/reuse-database-connections-aws-lambda/), I leave the function unused for 1+ hours and I can still see that the code is still in memory.

Comment: There is, indeed, no concrete timespan after which the VM gets destroyed. In some tests I made about a year ago, the VM was destroyed after ~15 minutes (AWS, you can verify this by printing something out in a static inttializer block). If you want to reuse database connection, use static initializers (I cave an example in [this blog post](https://labs.consol.de/development/2019/02/04/aws_lambda_getting_started.html)).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074990/

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/ does not help

Comment: Does [Aron Gupta's example](https://github.com/arun-gupta/lambda-rds-mysql) help?

Comment: Have you looked at the relatively new Lambda DB Proxy feature? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 1):

There's no documented time that I'm aware of. It will vary, depending on the needs of the Lambda service. Are you sure that the Lambda wasn't warm-started within that hour? One hour seems like a long time.

Also, look at [Lambda Provisioned Concurrency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-predictable-start-up-times-with-provisioned-concurrency/), RDS Proxy (in preview) and Aurora Serverless Data API (if you're using Aurora Serverless). They are all relevant to database connections from Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Code start official Duration is :-  100 ms to over 1 second. You can find it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)